# PHP Curl to get first image and first 25 words of text on a page

Tags: php, curl

The following two functions work perfectly to get the meta data from a url. First it gets the title of a webpage, then searches for a opengraph description tag. In the event it doesn't find an og:description it will fall back on the meta description.

What I want to happen is have a further fall back so if no meta description exists it will grab the first 25 words of text.

Equally I want to create a fall back on og:image so if none exists it will grab the first image it finds on the page.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

function getit($site) 
{
    $content = file_get_contents_curl($site);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($content);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) 
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') 
        {
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        } 
        elseif ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') 
        { 
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
        }
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') 
        {
        $image = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
        } 
    }
$str .= 'Title: '.$title.' <br/><br/>';
$str .= 'Description: '.$description.' <br/><br/>';
$str .= 'Image: <img src="'.$image.'">';
$str .= 'Image2: <img src="'.$firstimage.'">';
echo $str;
}
```

I am extremely new to using curl and not at all fluent with it, so I really don't know where to begin or end to modify my code to make this happen. I have added the binary transfer option to the curl setopt as I BELIEVE it will require a binarytransfer for an image, but really I am clueless as to what I am doing here and would appreciate any suggestions to how I go about doing this?

**UPDATES:**

I updated the above code to remove the binary transfer. I also added the following:

```
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Then for testing purposes I added:

```
$str .= 'Image2: <img src="'.$firstimage.'">';
```

SO I now have the firsst image being returned, still need to figure out hor to get the first 25 words of text on a page.

Comment: You're not fetching images. You're fetching HTML that (might) contains an `<img>` tag with a `src` attribute containing a url POINTING at where the image's binary data can be found. The binary bit is pointless, since html is just text.

Comment: @MarcB Based on what you are saying I am guessing I need to do something like $image = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); but how do I limit it to the first image it finds, equally how would I get the first 25 words of text in the body tag that are not other tags?

Comment: @Bruce you need to look at your current code and figure out how to modify what you have to make what you want ... it should be something like `$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body'); $description = $body->item(0)->nodeValue; $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('image'); $image = $images->item(0)-getAttribute('src');`

Comment: those `getXXX` functions return a nodelist, just fetch the first item in the list. that's your first image.

Comment: @MarcB that has helped me grab the first image, thank you. Any ideas about getting the first 25 words of text?

Comment: I have everything working now, just one final thing to figure out, and thats how to handle NULL errors.

Answer (score 0):

So for the 25 words, I called for the first paragraph tag and set the value of it as a string, then I exploded the string and called for the first 25 words. I set these as a variable so they could be echo'd out easy with a test.

For the first image, I added:

```
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Then I do a test to see if og:image was empty and if so I echo the first image instead.

```
<?
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

function getit($site) {

    $parsing = file_get_contents_curl($site);
    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($parsing);

    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $para = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
    //get and display what you need:

    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $firstparagraph = $para->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') {
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        } 
        elseif ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') { 
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        } else { 
            $descrition = "<p>".implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $firstparagraph), 0, 25))."</p>"; 
        }
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') {
            $image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }   
    }   

    if ($image != '') { $image = $image; } else { $image = $firstimage; }

    $str .= 'Title: '.$title.' <br/><br/>';
    $str .= 'Description: '.$description.' <br/><br/>';
    $str .= 'Image: <img src="'.$image.'"><br/><br/>';
    echo $str;
}

?>
```